# Plotting data from a list of rules, infer axis titles from the rules with units

Tags: plotting, data

I have data, with units, organized as a list of rules; this is so I can slice the data in different ways based on the variables represented.

I'm trying to find the most direct way to plot this and get axis titles with both the variable from the rule and unit from the values. I don't want to manually label the plots each time, so if Plot doesn't have a built-in then how can I write a function to do the inference? I'm looking for the most DRY approach possible.

This gives me the units, but not the variable names, in the labels:

```
data = {
   y -> {0, 33.2} (Quantity[1, ("KipsForce")/("Inches")^2]),
   x -> {0, 6} 10^-4
   };
ListLinePlot[Transpose@({x, y} /. data), AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

On the same example, is it possible to retain units like "in/in"? I've done this by manually specifying the labels and using `HoldForm` to avoid evaluating the cancellation, but I can't get that to work with automatic labels as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This does everything I asked</strike>, including keeping the in/in unit:

(edit) I want to be independent of the order of `data`, but for now it needs to be ordered according to the axes for this to work.

```
data = {
   x -> {0, 6} 10^-4 Quantity["in/in"]
   y -> {0, 33.2}    Quantity["ksi"],
   };

GetLabels = # /. ((a_ -> b_) :>
  Row[{a, " ", QuantityForm@QuantityUnit@b[[1]]}]) &;

ListLinePlot[Transpose@({x,y} /. data), AxesLabel -> GetLabels@data]
```

(edit) **More complete solution:**

I changed `GetLabels` to take a point so the labels are ordered according to the data as it's given to `Plot`

```
data = { y -> ..., x -> ... };

points = Transpose@({x, y} /. data);
kv = (points /. ({a_, b_} :> {x -> a, y -> b}));

GetLabels = # /. ((a_ -> b_) :> 
          Row[{a, " ", QuantityForm@QuantityUnit@b}]) &;

ListLinePlot[points, AxesLabel -> style`size[16] /@ GetLabels@kv[[1]]]
```

Comment: Your labels are on the wrong axes. You should change the definition of `data` to `data = Reverse@{y -> {0, 33.2} Quantity["ksi"], x -> {0, 6} 10^-4 Quantity["in/in"]};`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon you're absolutely right! I'll leave this unsolved because order independence is part of what I want out of this

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[data, x, y, assoc, labelFunc]
data = {x -> Map[Quantity[#, "in/in"] &]@({0, 6} 10^-4) , 
   y -> Map[Quantity[#, "ksi"] &]@({0, 33.2} )};
```

We define two `Associations` using `data`:

```
assoc = Association @ data;

labelingAssoc = Association @ KeyValueMap[# -> Quantity[#, #2] &] @ 
    QuantityUnit @ Map[First] @ assoc
```

> ```
>  <|x -> Quantity[x, ("Inches")/("Inches")],
>    y -> Quantity[y,("KipsForce")/("Inches")^2]|>
> ```

We can map the two associations on the list of variables

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[assoc /@ {x, y}], AxesLabel -> labelingAssoc /@ {x, y}]
```

or use them with as replacement rules

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, y} /. assoc],  AxesLabel -> {x, y} /. labelingAssoc]
```

to get

[image]

Alternatively, define a function for labeling

```
labelFunc = Map[Quantity[#, QuantityUnit @ First[assoc @ #]] &];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[assoc /@ {x, y}], AxesLabel -> labelFunc @ {x, y}]
```

[image]